# If I'm putting XML in the admin panel for one page can I start at the action?

Tags: admin, xml

I want to insert the twitter bootstrap CDN link into one page.  Im going to put it into the admin panel under that pages design tab.  For the XML can I start at the action?  Will the admin insertion append the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via layout XML. Magento allows you to tap into the `head` block to add CSS/JSS. Example:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <css>path/to/skin/css/style.css</css>
    </action>
</reference>
```

And this could be placed in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml for the moment while you test. However, this is not good enough in the case of an external asset, because the head block's `addCss` method will only resolve URIs relative to the server on which the store is hosted.

There are extensions that work around this. For example, see http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/

Now you could do almost the same thing yourself without the extension, by using **this** layout XML instead:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="bootstrap_cdn">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.url/to/bootstrap.css" />
            ]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Here we create a basic block and insert some custom text, which really just a `link` tag.

**Clarification**

Now you mention wanting to do this on the admin page edit areas. I presume this means the CMS page/block editor areas. If so, are you actually asking about loading Bootstrap into the TinyMCE editor? If so, I have an extension for this: https://github.com/vbuck/rootd-tinymce

Now, please note that if you want to target those areas of admin only, you will need to place the above `reference` node into the right layout action handle node: `adminhtml_cms_page_edit`.

If you're new to layout XML, start here:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/

Comment: I can add custom XML under the design tab with each page. Its below the dropdown that asks me what template I want to use.  Does Magento append any xml to what I put there?  Can I start at <action>?

Comment: Ahh, ok. Now I understand, I'll add a new answer.

Comment: No need.It works by treating it as if you were editing code files. Thank You for your help. Thats what I was looking for.